# Jquery Show and Hide Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get this to work where when they select the search between dates it will show the second date search field.

I know that the jquery is pulling in that value for the select menu bc I can put an alert for it and when I click on the search between dates it throws the alert at me, my only problem is getting it to show that hidden input.

HTML:

```
<select name='filter' class='input-large' id="select_field">
    <option value=''>Select One</option>
    <option value='dateonly'>Search by Date Only</option>
    <option value='search_between_dates'>Search Between Dates</option>
</select>
<input type='text' placeholder="Date">
<input type="text" placeholder="Date 2" id="date2_hiddden" class="hidden">
```

Javascript:

```
function getSelect() {
    var selectValue = $("#select_field").val();
    if(selectValue === 'search_between_dates') {
        $("#date2_hidden").show(function() {
            $("#date2_hidden");
        })
    } else {
        $("#date2_hidden").hide();
    }
}
$("#select_field").change(getSelect);
getSelect();
```

Neither of these work and putting the id instead of class for the second still doesn't work.

```
function getSelect() {
    var selectValue = $("#select_field").val();
    if(selectValue === 'search_between_dates') {
        $(".hidden").show();
    } else {
        $("#date2_hidden").hide();
    }
}
$("#select_field").change(getSelect);
getSelect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed your HTML had date2_hidden with 3 "d"s.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/H6Hhw/1/

```
function getSelect() {    
    var selectValue = $("#select_field").val();

    if (selectValue === 'search_between_dates') {
        $("#date2_hidden").show();
    } else {
        $("#date2_hidden").hide();
    }
}

$("#select_field").on('change', function () {
    getSelect();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use only

```
if(selectValue === 'search_between_dates') {
    $("#date2_hidden").show();
} else {
    $("#date2_hidden").hide();
}
```

not understand why you did it:

```
$("#date2_hidden").show(function() {
   $("#date2_hidden");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

in your html

```
id="date2_hiddden"
```

with 3 'd'

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pascalz/XWZ5Q/)